# Windows command prompt - I have a space in the folder name

Tags: command-line

I am trying to run a command

```
npm init -y
```

in the Windows command prompt

My folder name has a space in it.

```
C:\Dans\Courses\Free Courses\JavaScript ES6
```

I get:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.48]
(c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\First>cd C:\Dans\Courses\Free Courses\JavaScript ES6

C:\Dans\Courses\Free Courses\JavaScript ES6>npm init -y
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.17134
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "init" "-y"
npm ERR! node v6.10.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10

npm ERR! Invalid name: "JavaScript ES6"
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Dans\Courses\Free Courses\JavaScript ES6\npm-debug.log

C:\Dans\Courses\Free Courses\JavaScript ES6>
```

---

I tried quotes around it with no success.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an open issue: https://github.com/npm/init-package-json/issues/72

Who uses spaces in folder names anyway ;)

Comment: I do for clarity..:). Also, that error output is not the same as what I get but appears similar.